# Laravel query goup by, multipe coulmn count with groupby

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, query-builder

I have a query let's take a look,

```
DB::table('states')
    ->join('brands', 'brands.state_id', '=', 'states.state_id')
    ->join('cities', 'cities.state_id', '=', 'states.state_id')
    ->select(
        'state_name',
        DB::raw("(COUNT('cities.city_id')) as cities"),
        DB::raw("count('brands.brand_id') as brands")
    )
    ->groupBy('state_name')
    ->get();
```

I want to get the `state_name` from the `states` table & count the `cities` and `brands` under the state. But in these queries, the problem is city counts & brand counts show the same result. How can I fix that?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: my expected result will display the state_name with city--count & brand--count

Comment: like this : `
[
{
state_name: "Alabama",
cities: 574,
brands: 5
},
{
state_name: "Arkansas",
cities: 439,
brands: 6
},
{
state_name: "Arkansas",
cities: 439,
brands: 10
}
]
`

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: the cities & brands are the same as cities:530 brand:530 but it's not the right answer. brands have a different value

Comment: @530,For all the state_name?or just for one state_name?you should clarify your output.

Comment: cities & brands changed on different state_name but  the cities == brands that means the first count equals to second count

Comment: Do you have models set up for these tables?

Answer (score 0):

Change `join(...` (INNER JOIN) to `leftJoin(...` (LEFT JOIN).